# PDO get database value of a user while logging in and store it to $_SESSION

Tags: php, mysql, session, pdo

I'v been working on this for days now and yet can't get it sorted. I have a register form and a logi form. All i want to do is to save retrieve user's data while he's logging in and save it whenhis session is active.Here is my latest try 
this is my inscription.php(register part)

```
<?php //script pour vérifier et enregistrer les données
            ini_set('display_errors',1); 
            if (isset($_POST['submit']))
            {
                //on récupère les données entrées
                $name = ucfirst($_POST['userName']); //mettre le premier caractère en majuscule
                $firstName = ucfirst($_POST['firstName']);
                $birthDate = $_POST['year'].'-'.$_POST['month'].'-'.$_POST['day'];
                $languageM = $_POST['langueM']; //langue maternelle
                $languageE = $_POST['langueE']; //langue étudiée
                $niveau = $_POST['level'];//niveau première langue étudiée
                $langueAjoutee = $_POST['secondeLangue'];
                $niveau2 = $_POST['level2'];
                $email =  $_POST['mailInput'].'@'.$_POST['schools'];
                $password1 = $_POST['password1'];
                $password2 = $_POST['password2'];

                if(isset($name,$firstName,$birthDate,$languageM,$languageE,$niveau,$email,$password1,$password2))
                {

                    if ($password1===$password2)
                    {
                        //hashage du mot de passe
                        $password1_sha1 = sha1($password1);
                        $password2_sha1 = sha1($password2);
                        // si utilisateur déjà enregistré
                        $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=bladuo', 'root', '');
                        $bdd->exec('SET NAMES utf8');//affichage caractères utf-8 dans la bdd
                        $stmt= $bdd->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM `membres` WHERE email=?");
                        $stmt->execute(array($email));
                        while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
                        {
                            $email_count = $row["count"];
                        }
                        //if email already used

                        else
                        {
                        //check password length 

                            else
                            {   
                             //connection à la bdd
                                try
                                {
                                    $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=bladuo', 'root', '');
                                    $bdd->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
                                    $bdd->exec('SET NAMES utf8');//affichage caractères utf-8 dans la bdd



                                    //enregistrement de l'étudiant dans la bdd
                                    $stmt =  $bdd->prepare('INSERT INTO                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              members(nom,prenom,date_de_naissance,langue_maternelle,langue_etudiee,niveau,langu2,niveau2,email,passe)
                                           VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,?)');
                                    $success = $stmt->execute(array($name , $firstName , $birthDate, $languageM ,                                                                         $languageE,$niveau,$langueAjoutee,$niveau2,$email,$password1_sha1)); 

                                    if($success)//si l'utilisateur est enregistré dans la bdd
                                    {   
                                        header('Location: Index.php');
                                    }else

                                    {    
                                       echo "INSERT a echouer!!";
                                       exit();
                                    }
                                }
                                catch(Exception $e)
                                {
                                    die('Erreur : '.$e->getMessage());
                                } 
                            }

                        }

                    }else 
                    {
                        print "<span style=\"color:red;\">Les mots de passe ne sont pas identiques</span>";
                        exit();
                    }

                    }else
                    {
                        print "<span style=\"color:red;\">une des variables n'est pas attribuée</span>";
                    }          

            }
        ?>
```

and my reg.php(for the login form)

```
<?php 
ini_set('display_errors',1); 
error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);
session_start();
$errmsg_arr = array();
$errflag = false;

    // connexion db
   $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=bladuo', 'root', '');
   $bdd->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    // nouvelle donnée
    $mail = $_POST['mail'];
    $password = $_POST['pwd'];
    $password_sha =sha1($password);
    if($mail == '') {
        $errmsg_arr[] = 'Veuillez entrer votre addresse email';
        $errflag = true;
    }
    if($password == '') {
        $errmsg_arr[] = 'Veuillez entrer votre mot de passe';
        $errflag = true;
    }

    // query
    $result = $bdd->prepare("SELECT * FROM members WHERE email=? AND passe=?");
    $result->bindParam(1,$mail);
    $result->bindParam(2,$password_sha);
    $result->execute();
    $rows = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
    print_r($rows);
    if($result->rowCount() == 1) 
    { 
       $getUsers = $bdd->prepare("SELECT * FROM members WHERE nom=? AND email=?");
       $getUsers->bindParam(1,$name);
       $getUsers->bindParam(2,$email);
       $getUsers->execute();
       $users = $getUsers->fetch();
       print_r($users);
       while($user = $getUsers->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM)){
        $_SESSION['nom']=$users['nom'];
        $_SESSION['email']=$users['email'];
       }
    $bdd->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
       header("location: Accueil.php"); 
    } else 
    {
        $errmsg_arr[] = "Email ou mot de passe incorrecte ou vide"; 
        $errflag = true; 
    }
    if($errflag) {
        $_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR'] = $errmsg_arr;
        session_write_close();
        header("location: Index.php");
        exit();
    }
```

?>

Any help is appreciated

Comment: What is it doing now (or not doing now)?

Comment: i get undefined index whenever i try to echo <?php echo $_SESSION['email']; ?> or <?php echo $_SESSION['nom']; ?>

Comment: Well it's strange that you are looping through those. Are there supposed to be multiple emails and names?

Comment: Also what you do you get where you have written `print_r($users);`?

Comment: it doesn't show me anything.When i miss up with my sql commands i get an array of the user's informations

Comment: for the email and name i just want it for the logged in user

Comment: Try doing a class and see if you can get something to return.

Comment: You **uregently** need to read up on [proper password hashing in PHP](http://www.phptherightway.com/#password_hashing) because wrapping the password in SHA1 without a salt is nowhere near good enough.

Comment: Use `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` instead of `PDO::FETCH_NUM`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Along with making sure your variables are passed to this page properly, as suggested by @ Kypros, maybe try using a class system.

**user class**

```
<?php
    class SetUserInfo
        {
            // Database connection
            public  $db;
            // Error reporting
            public  $error;
            // Set to check pass1 = pass 2
            public  $passCheck;
            // Storage for user submission data
            public  $useInfo;

            protected   $host       =   'localhost';
            protected   $database   =   'dbname';
            protected   $user       =   'username';
            protected   $pass       =   'password';

            public  function __construct()
                {
                    // Save db connection
                    $this->db   =   new DBEngine($this->host,$this->database,$this->user,$this->pass);
                }

            // This method pulls user from system
            public  function FetchUser($pass, $email)
                {
                    // If the email address is valid, fetch from db
                    if(filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
                            $info   =   $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM members WHERE passe=? AND email=?");
                            $info->bindParam(1,$pass);
                            $info->bindParam(2,$email);
                            $info->execute();
                            // If there are rows, set them to an array
                            if($info->rowCount() == 1) {
                                    $user   =   $info->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                                }
                        }

                    // Return the user array if validated or else return false/0
                    return (isset($user))? $user:0;
                }

            // This should return the count
            public  function EmailCount()
                {
                    // Assign email from previously assigned email [ from Process() array ]
                    $query  =   $this->db->con->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM `members` WHERE email=?");
                    $query->execute(array($this->useInfo['email']));

                    while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                            $count = $row["count"];
                        }

                    if(isset($count) && $count == 1)
                        $this->error['email']['available']  =   'Compte d\'utilisateur déjà dans le système';

                    return (isset($count) && $count == 1)? 1:0;
                }

            public  function CreateRegistration($errors = false)
                {
                //  print_r($this->useInfo);

                    $this->db->con->exec('SET NAMES utf8');
                    //enregistrement de l'étudiant dans la bdd
                    $query = $this->db->con->prepare('INSERT INTO                                                                                                            members (nom,prenom,date_de_naissance,langue_maternelle,langue_etudiee,niveau,langu2,niveau2,email,passe) 
                    VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)');

                    $query->bindParam(1,$this->useInfo['name']);
                    $query->bindParam(2,$this->useInfo['firstName']);
                    $query->bindParam(3,$this->useInfo['birthDate']);
                    $query->bindParam(4,$this->useInfo['languageM']);
                    $query->bindParam(5,$this->useInfo['languageE']);
                    $query->bindParam(6,$this->useInfo['niveau']);
                    $query->bindParam(7,$this->useInfo['langueAjoutee']);
                    $query->bindParam(8,$this->useInfo['niveau2']);
                    $query->bindParam(9,$this->useInfo['email']);
                    $query->bindParam(10,$this->useInfo['passe']);
                    $query->execute();

                    // Validate user right.
                    $user   =   $this->ValidateLogin($this->useInfo['email'],$this->useInfo['passe'],0);

                    // Toggle error reporting on and off. Default is off.
                    if($errors == true || $errors == 1) { ?>
                        <pre>
                        <?php
                        // Print sql error
                        print_r($query->errorInfo());
                        // Print all values set to be inserted
                        print_r($this->useInfo);
                        // Print post
                        print_r($_POST); ?>
                        </pre>
                        <?php }

                    // Send back success or failure
                    return (is_array($user))? 1:0;
                }

            public  $loginVars;
            public  function ValidateLogin($email = '',$password = '',$validate=1)
                {
                    // Check that email is valid
                    $this->loginVars['mail']    =   (isset($email) && filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))? $email:0;
                    // Check that password is not empty
                    $this->loginVars['pwd']     =   (isset($password) && !empty($password))? $password:0;

                    // If there are no problems check database
                    if(!in_array('0',$this->loginVars)) {

                            // Assign encryption or process raw (could registration has encrytion alredy)
                            $this->loginVars['password_sha']    =   ($validate == 1)? sha1($this->loginVars['pwd']):$this->loginVars['pwd'];
                            // Prepare to check db
                            $query                              =   $this->db->con->prepare("SELECT * FROM `members` WHERE email=? AND passe=?");
                            $query->bindParam(1,$this->loginVars['mail']);
                            $query->bindParam(2,$this->loginVars['password_sha']);

                            // Execute search
                            $query->execute();

                            // If there are returned rows (1 specifically) set to array
                            if($query->rowCount() == 1) {
                                    $rows   =   $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                                    return $rows;
                                }
                            else {
                                    $this->error['login']['error']  =   'Échec de la connexion.';
                                    return 0;
                                }
                        }
                    else {
                            if($this->loginVars['email'] == 0)
                                $this->error['invalid']['email']    =   'Veuillez entrer votre addresse email';
                            if($this->loginVars['pwd'] == 0)
                                $this->error['invalid']['pwd']    =   'Veuillez entrer votre mot de passe';

                            return 0;
                        }

                }

            // Processor $_POSTs
            protected function Process()
                {
                    // Process if $_POST is set
                    if(isset($_POST['userName'])) {
                            $this->useInfo['name']          =   (!empty($_POST['userName']))? ucfirst($_POST['userName']):"";
                            $this->useInfo['firstName']     =   (!empty($_POST['firstName']))? ucfirst($_POST['firstName']):"";
                            $this->useInfo['birthDate']     =   (!empty($_POST['year']) && !empty($_POST['month']) && !empty($_POST['day']))? $_POST['year'].'-'.$_POST['month'].'-'.$_POST['day']:"";
                            $this->useInfo['languageM']     =   (!empty($_POST['langueM']))? $_POST['langueM']:"";
                            $this->useInfo['languageE']     =   (!empty($_POST['langueE']))? $_POST['langueE']:"";
                            $this->useInfo['niveau']        =   (!empty($_POST['level']))? $_POST['level']:"";
                            $this->useInfo['langueAjoutee'] =   (!empty($_POST['secondeLangue']))? $_POST['secondeLangue']:"";
                            $this->useInfo['niveau2']       =   (!empty($_POST['level2']))? $_POST['level2']:"";
                            $this->useInfo['email']         =   (!empty($_POST['mailInput']) && !empty($_POST['schools']))? $_POST['mailInput'].'@'.$_POST['schools']:"";
                            $this->useInfo['password1']     =   (!empty($_POST['password1']))? $_POST['password1']:"";
                            $this->useInfo['password2']     =   (!empty($_POST['password2']))? $_POST['password2']:"";

                            // Set password equivalent check
                            $pcheck =   ($this->useInfo['password1'] == $this->useInfo['password2'])? true:false;
                            if($pcheck == true) {
                                    // This is where you would run a validation on password
                                    // For instance -> check password length (I chose 8, but you never supplied that code)
                                    $length =   8;
                                    if(strlen($this->useInfo['password1']) >= 8) {
                                            $this->passCheck['password_sha']    =   sha1($this->useInfo['password1']);
                                            $this->useInfo['passe']             =   $this->passCheck['password_sha'];
                                            // Remove unused value
                                            unset($this->useInfo['password1'],$this->useInfo['password2']);
                                            // $this->passCheck['p2']     =   sha1($this->useInfo['password2']);
                                        }
                                    else
                                        $this->error['password']['length']  =   'Le mot de passe doit être de '.$length.'                                                                                     caractères';  
                                }
                            else
                                $this->error['password']['id']  =   'Les mots de passe ne sont pas identiques';
                    }

                    // Return only if the array is set and not empty
                    return (isset($this->useInfo) && !empty($this->useInfo))? $this->useInfo: 0;
                }

            public  function Validate()
                {
                    // Set all the prefs to array
                    $user   =   $this->Process();
                    // If the array is filled with something
                    if(!empty($user)) {
                            // Loop through the returned array
                            foreach($user as $key => $value) {
                                    // If there were any empty fields, assign them to an error array
                                    if(empty($value))
                                        $this->error['validate'][]  =   $key;
                                }

                            // This will only return the array IF there are no errors
                            // If you want something less strict, just remove the $this->error condition
                            return (!isset($this->error['validate']))? $user : 'err';
                        }
                    else
                        // Return false/0 if the user array is empty
                        return 0;
                }
        } ?>
```

**connection class**

```
<?php
    class   DBEngine
        {
            public  $con;
            public  $errors;
            public  function __construct($host="",$db = "",$user="",$pass="")
                {
                    try {
                            $this->con  =   new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db",$user,$pass, array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING));
                        }
                    catch (Exception $e) {
                          $this->errors['connect']['message']    =   $e->getMessage();
                          $this->errors['connect']['error_code'] =   $e->getCode();
                          print_r($this->errors);
                        }
                }

            // Simple fetch and return method
            public  function Fetch($_sql)
                {
                    $query  =   $this->con->prepare($_sql);
                    $query->execute();
                    $this->errors['fetch'][]    =   $query->errorInfo();

                    if($query->rowCount() > 0) {
                            while($rows = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                                    $array[]    =   $rows;
                                }
                        }

                    return (isset($array) && $array !== 0 && !empty($array))? $array: 0;
                }

            // Simple write to db method
            public  function Write($_sql)
                {
                    $query  =   $this->con->prepare($_sql);
                    $query->execute();
                    $this->errors['insert'][]   =   $query->errorInfo();
                }
        } ?>
```

**register page**

```
<?php
//Registration workflow
ini_set('display_errors',1); 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
// Register User
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        include('class.user.php');
        include('class.connect.php');
        $info   =   new SetUserInfo();
        // If info is all filled

        if(is_array($info->Validate())) {
                // If the passwords equal each other & is the correct
                // length of characters
                if(isset($info->passCheck['password_sha'])) {
                        // This is supposed to return the count
                        // if email exists already
                        $_emailInSys    =   $info->EmailCount();
                        // If email not in the system insert values for registration
                        if($_emailInSys == 0) {
                                // Insert into database
                                $success    =   $info->CreateRegistration();
                                // If success, forward to index
                                if($success == 1)
                                    header('Location: Index.php');
                            }
                    }
            }
    }
?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Accueil</title>
<script src="../js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="../js/myjavascript.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<style>
label.error { color: red; float: left; clear: left; font-size: 10px; text-transform: uppercase; margin-bottom: 5px; }
#errors     { background-color: #C00; color: #FFF; border-radius: 4px; padding: 10px 20px; font-size: 14px; text-shadow: 1px 1px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.4); display: none; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }
#errorcont  { display: inline-block; }
</style>

</head>

<body>
<?php include("header.php"); ?>
<div id="formulaireInscription">
    <h3 id="titreIncrivez">Inscrivez-vous!</h3>
    <div id="numstyle">
    </div>
    <form action="Inscription.php" method="POST" id="registration">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div id="renseignementgenerale" class="form-group">
            <div id="errorcont">
                <div id="errors"></div>
            </div>
                <label for="userName">Nom:
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="userName" placeholder="Entrez votre nom" required="required">
                </label>
                <br />
                <label for="firstName">Prénom:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="firstName" placeholder="Entrez votre prénom" required="required">
                <div class="form-group" id="birthdate">
                    <label>Date de naissance:</label>
                    <label for="dayInput">Jour</label>
                    <select name="day">
                        <option value="">Jour</option>
                        <?php for ($i = 1; $i <= 31; $i++) { ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $i; ?>"><?php echo $i; ?></option>
                        <?php   } ?>
                    </select>
                    <label for"monthInput">Mois</label>
                    <select name="month">
                        <option value="">Mois</option>
                        <option value="01">Janvier</option>
                        <option value="02">Février</option>
                        <option value="03">Mars</option>
                        <option value="04">Avril</option>
                        <option value="05">Mai</option>
                        <option value="06">Juin</option>
                        <option value="07">juillet</option>
                        <option value="08">Aout</option>
                        <option value="09">Septembre</option>
                        <option value="10">Octobre</option>
                        <option value="11">Novembre</option>
                        <option value="12">Décembre</option>
                    </select>
                    <label for"yearInput">Année</label>
                    <select name="year">
                        <option value="">Année</option>
                        <?php
                                for ($i = 2014; $i >= 1930; $i--)
                                {
                                    echo '<option value="' . $i . '">' . $i . '</option>';
                                }
                            ?>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group" id="langueM">
                    <label>Langue maternelle:</label>
                    <select  name="langueM">
                        <option value="français">Français</option>
                        <option value="anglais">Anglais</option>
                        <option value="espagnol">Espagnol</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group" id="langueE">
                    <label>Langue étudiée:</label>
                    <select  name="langueE">
                        <option value="anglais">Anglais</option>
                        <option value="espagnol">Espagnol</option>
                        <option value="français">Français</option>
                    </select>
                    <label>Niveau:</label>
                    <select name=level id="niveau">
                        <option value="B1">B1</option>
                        <option value="B2">B2</option>
                        <option value="C1">C1</option>
                        <option value="C2">C2</option>
                    </select>
                    <img id="plus" title="Cliquer sur l'image pour ajouter une seconde langue" src="../res/images/boutons/plus.png"> <a class="level" ><strong><em>Comment choisir mon niveau?</em></strong> <span> B1:Je participe à des conversations sur des sujets<br />
                        simples et familiers.<br />
                        B2:Je peux discuter avec aisance et une certaine<br />
                        spontanéité.<br />
                        C1:Je m’exprime spontanément sans trop chercher<br />
                        mes mots<br />
                        C2:Je m’exprime et comprends sans efforts et<br />
                        je souhaite maintenir mon niveau. </span> </a><br />
                    <script>
                            document.getElementById('plus').onclick = function() {//cacher le bouton et afficher le select
                                    document.getElementById('addLanguage').style.display = 'inline';
                                    document.getElementById('plus').style.display = 'none';
                            }
                        </script>
                    <div id="addLanguage">
                        <select id="langu2" name="secondeLangue">
                            <option value="espagnol">Espagnol</option>
                            <option value="anglais">Anglais</option>
                            <option value="français">Français</option>
                        </select>
                        <label>Niveau:</label>
                        <select name=level2 id="niveau2">
                            <option value="B1">B1</option>
                            <option value="B2">B2</option>
                            <option value="C1">C1</option>
                            <option value="C2">C2</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <label >Adresse email:</label>
            <div>
                <div class="mailliste">
                    <input name="mailInput" type="text" placeholder="Entrez votre email" required="required">
                    @
                    <select name="schools" onchange="VerifListe();">
                        <option value="rms.fr">rms.fr</option>
                        <option value="icade.es">icade.es</option>
                        <option value="esb.de">esb.de</option>
                    </select>
                    <a href=""><img id="question" src="../res/images/boutons/question.png"> <span> Vous pouvez vous inscrire<br />
                        uniquement avec <strong><em>votre adresse Email<br />
                        de votre école.</em></strong> Pour consulter la liste<br />
                        des écoles patenaires cliquez ici. </span> </a>
                </div>
                <br>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inscriptionInputPassword1">Mot de passe:</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password1" name="password1" placeholder="Entrez votre mode passe" required="required">
            <br>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password2" name="password2" placeholder="Répétez votre mode passe" required="required">
        </div>
        <div class="myButtons">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Inscription"/>
            <input type="button" value="Retour" onclick="document.location.href='Index.php';" />
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    <?php if(isset($info->error)) {
                foreach($info->error as $kind => $container) {
                        $imploder[] =   str_replace('"','\"',ucwords(implode("<br />",$container)));
                    }
                 ?>
                $("#errors").html("<?php echo implode("<br />",$imploder); ?>");
                $("#errors").delay(500).fadeIn("slow");
                $("#errors").delay(3000).fadeOut("slow");
    <?php } ?>

    // validate signup form on keyup and submit
    $("#registration").validate({
        rules: {
            userName: {
                required: true
            },
            day: {
                required: true
            },
            month: {
                required: true
            },
            year: {
                required: true
            },
            mail: {
                required: true,
                email: true//,
                //minlength: 4
            },
            password1: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 8
            },
            password2: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 8,
                equalTo: "#password1"
            }
        },
        messages: {
            mail: {
                required: "Nom d'utilisateur Obligatoire",
                email: "Adresse email invalide"
            },
            password1: {
                required: "Mot de passe requis",
                minlength: "8 caractères minimum"
            },
            password2: {
                required: "Mot de passe requis",
                minlength: "8 caractères minimum",
                equalTo: "Not the same"
            }
        }
    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**login page**

```
<?php
session_start();
ini_set('display_errors',0); 
error_reporting(0);

    if(isset($_POST['cesam'])) {
            include('class.user.php');
            include('class.connect.php');
            $info       =   new SetUserInfo();
            $userData   =   $info->ValidateLogin($_POST['mail'],$_POST['pwd']);

            if($userData !== 0) {
                    $_SESSION['email']              =   $userData['mail'];
                    $_SESSION['nom']                =   $userData['nom'];
                    $_SESSION['date_de_naissance']  =   $userData['date_de_naissance'];
                    $_SESSION['langue_maternelle']  =   $userData['langue_maternelle'];
                    $_SESSION['langue_etudiee']     =   $userData['langue_etudiee'];
                    $_SESSION['niveau']             =   $userData['niveau'];
                    $_SESSION['langu2']             =   $userData['langu2'];
                    $_SESSION['niveau2']            =   $userData['niveau2'];
                    header("location: Accueil.php");
                }
        }
?><!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Accueil</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<style>
label.error { color: red; float: left; clear: left; font-size: 10px; text-transform: uppercase; margin-bottom: 5px; }
#errors     { background-color: #C00; color: #FFF; border-radius: 4px; padding: 10px 20px; font-size: 14px; text-shadow: 1px 1px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.4); display: none; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }
#errorcont  { display: inline-block; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<?php  include("header.php"); ?>
<div id="intro">
    <h2><span>Bladuo, Qu'est ce que c'est ?</span></h2>
</div>
<div id="errorcont">
    <div id="errors"></div>
</div>
<div id="formulaireConnexion">
    <form class="form-horizontal" action="Index.php" method="POST" id="login">
        <input type="email" name="mail" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Email">
        <br />
        <input type="password" name="pwd" class="form-control" id="inputPassword3" placeholder="Mot de passe">
        <input type="checkbox">
        Se souvenir de moi
        <button type="submit" name="cesam" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" role="button">Se connecter</button>
        <a href="Inscription.php" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" role="button">S'inscrire</a>
    </form>
</div>
<div id="videoPresentation">
    <iframe width="560" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/CqSDWoAhvLU" allowfullscreen> </iframe>
</div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    <?php if(isset($info->error)) {
                foreach($info->error as $kind => $container) {
                        $imploder[] =   str_replace('"','\"',implode("",$container));
                    }
                 ?>
                $("#errors").html("<?php echo implode("",$imploder); ?>");
                $("#errors").delay(500).fadeIn("slow");
                $("#errors").delay(2000).fadeOut("slow");
    <?php } ?>

    // validate signup form on keyup and submit
    $("#login").validate({
        rules: {
            mail: {
                required: true,
                email: true//,
                //minlength: 4
            },
            pwd: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 8
            }
        },
        messages: {
            mail: {
                required: "Nom d'utilisateur Obligatoire",
                email: "Adresse email invalide"
            },
            pwd: {
                required: "Mot de passe requis",
                minlength: "8 caractères minimum"
            }
        }
    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I've never work with classes in php i'll read a bit about it.Thank you for sharing

Comment: this will be great  cause right now my code is like a recycle bin.

Comment: This refactoring is just one step towards creating an ORM, so why not spend the time to learn a [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) that has already implemented and tested all of this for you? Either you use a framework and benefit from the community code that comes with it, or you write your own nobody has ever seen and you're going to have to do everything yourself.

Comment: @tadman If the people at Laravel thought that way, there would be no Laravel. We'd all be modifying someone else's same 'ol code. I am not the greatest programmer in the world (mediocre at best) and programming is not my "official" field of expertise, so when you say "you're going to have to do everything yourself," I say there's nothing wrong with that. I learned a lot by doing everything myself. You have a valid point, but you make it sound as if Kuma is teetering on a cliff by not using a pre-made framework. If they learn some class basics, great. If not, they'll stick with what they know.

Comment: @Rasclatt Not using a framework is always risky. The people that wrote Laravel no doubt used many, many other frameworks before that and learned from them, found ways to improve upon them. Writing your own with no idea what a framework is never helped anyone. Yes, you are teetering on a cliff by not using one. You're wasting your time re-inventing what has already been coded professionally, tested, and embraced by a community. Why do so many people in the PHP community insist on doing everything from the ground up? Ruby, Python and even Perl are not like this.

Comment: @Rasclatt thank you mate, i did not test it yet but i'll do it tomorrow.No time with the job

Comment: @Rasclatt i'm getting error at this line  return (isset($useInfo) && !empty(array_filter($useInfo)))? $useInfo: 0; saying (Can't use function return value in write context)

Comment: No problem :) First i linked both of my forms to user.php where i copied the code.Is that good? I'm still looking to solve the error

Comment: Sorry that one line that is giving you issues is because I forgot to switch that variable. It's supposed to be `$this->useInfo` not `$useInfo`

Comment: Also, part of what I am guessing is how these two instances work on your page(s). One I is a registering workflow, the other is a validating workflow. I tried to keep all the code based on what you've already created so you can read it still and know what things are doing based on what you already know of your code.

Comment: edited like this  return (isset($this->useInfo) && !empty(array_filter($this->useInfo)))? $this->useInfo: 0; but still same deal

Comment: Ok....there see if that gets rid of that error! I am pretty sure that is what the problem is.

Comment: I tried to log in and i'm getting a blank page @ user.php and for the registration i get several errors.

Comment: What are the odds you can post or email me your interacting pages without db login info? This sort of thing bothers me when I can't solve a problem. It's hard to update your current page without knowing what comes before it.

Comment: Plus, if there are multiple errors, I can quickly fix them if I know what lines they are occurring on.

Answer (score 0):

In your `reg.php` you bind two parameters:

```
   $getUsers->bindParam(1,$name);
   $getUsers->bindParam(2,$email);
```

Yet unless this file is included from elsewhere these are not set beforehand.

For the email you get the posted field through and then try to use the variable `$email` not `$mail`

```
$mail = $_POST['mail'];
```

For the `$name` you never seem to declare it anywhere. Ie with:

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
```

I suggest you turn error reporting on so it displays all errors and warnings as they happen, as it will make your life alot easier while developing

Comment: well this is supposed to be the name the user entered during registration

Comment: i'm looking to get my registration's value when the user is loggin in

Comment: Setting your session is dependent on the setting of `$email` and `$name`but you set `$mail` not `$email` and I don't see `$name` anyhere.

Comment: i have them on my inscrption.php . should i set them in the login page?

Comment: Yes you should since this is a different submitted form. Also there's no need to execute that query twice since you are already returning the user if the given username/password combination is correct to `$rows` after removing `PDO::FETCH_NUM`. Then you'll have the user to do as you want

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely use a class, it's not hard and it will help you  organize your code.

I wrote one for you:

```
<?php
Class User{

private $name; 
private firstName;
private birthDate;
private languageM;
private languageE; 
private niveau;
private langueAjoutee;
private niveau2;
private email;
private password;

//la connection pdo
private $bdd;

    function __construct(){
        $this->bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=bladuo', 'root', '');
        $this->bdd->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $this->bdd->exec('SET NAMES utf8');
    }

    function check_if_user_exists($email){
        $stmt= $this->bdd->prepare("SELECT email FROM `membres` WHERE email=?");
        $stmt->execute(array($email));
        return ($stmt->rowCount()==0);
    }

    function register_user(){
        try
        {
            $password_sha1 =sha1($this->password);
            $stmt =  $this->bdd->prepare('INSERT INTO members(nom,prenom,date_de_naissance,langue_maternelle,langue_etudiee,niveau,langu2,niveau2,email,passe)
                                   VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,?)');
            $success = $stmt->execute(array($this->name , $this->firstName , 
                                            $this->birthDate, $this->languageM ,
                                            $this->languageE,$this->niveau,
                                            $this->langueAjoutee,$this->niveau2,
                                            $this->email,$password_sha1)); 
            if($success && $stmt->rowCount() > 0){  
                return true;
            }else{    
               echo "INSERT a echouer!!";
               return false;
            }
        }
        catch(Exception $e)
        {
            die('Erreur : '.$e->getMessage());
            return false;
        }   
    }

    function login_user($username, $password){
        $password_sha1 =sha1($this->password);

        $result = $this->bdd->prepare("SELECT * FROM members WHERE email=? AND passe=?");
        $result->bindParam(1,$mail);
        $result->bindParam(2,$password_sha);
        $result->execute();

        if($result->rowCount() == 1){ 
            $row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);//print_r($row);
            return $row;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }

}
?>
```

**Usage for register:**

```
<?php
include 'Users.php';

if(isset($_POST['userName'],
         $_POST['firstName'],
         $_POST['year'],
         $_POST['month'],
         $_POST['day'],
         $_POST['langueM'],
         $_POST['langueE'],
         $_POST['level'],
         $_POST['secondeLangue'],
         $_POST['level2'],
         $_POST['mailInput'],
         $_POST['schools'],
         $_POST['password1'], 
         $_POST['password2'])){

    //une instance du user object    
    $user = new User();

    $email =  $_POST['mailInput'].'@'.$_POST['schools'];
    if($_POST['password1'] === $_POST['password2']){
        if($user->check_if_user_exists($email)){
            //set les values
            $user->name = ucfirst($_POST['userName']); 
            $user->firstName = ucfirst($_POST['firstName']);
            $user->birthDate = $_POST['year'].'-'.$_POST['month'].'-'.$_POST['day'];
            $user->languageM = $_POST['langueM']; 
            $user->languageE = $_POST['langueE']; 
            $user->niveau = $_POST['level'];
            $user->langueAjoutee = $_POST['secondeLangue'];
            $user->niveau2 = $_POST['level2'];
            $user->email =  $_POST['mailInput'].'@'.$_POST['schools'];
            $user->password = $_POST['password1'];
            //register the user
            if($user->register_user()){
                // "User registered!"   
                header('Location: Index.php');
            }else{
                die("user failed to register");
            }

        }else{
            die("User exist already!");
        }       
    }else{
        die("Password n'est pas correct");
    }

}
```

**Usage for login:**

```
<?php
include 'Users.php';

if(isset($_POST['mail'],$_POST['pwd'])){    
    $mail = $_POST['mail'];
    $password = $_POST['pwd'];  

    $user = new User();
    if($user->login_user($mail, $pass)){
        header("location: Accueil.php");
        exit;       
    }else{
        die("mot de passe ou mail invalid!");
    }
}
```

Not tested, but you should get the idea, I do trust that if any typo found you can fix it.

hope this helps

Comment: Is it normal that i'm getting "mot de passe ou email Invalid" even with a correct email and password?

Comment: Unless you have more than 1 record matching so you should change to rowCount()>0

Comment: Essaye d'ajouter un echo pour voir combien de rows sont trouveé

Comment: So there are 2 things.When i login, i get a blank page at user.php  when i register, i get undefined variable $bdd at line 25 user.php

Comment: @Kuma sorry I missed the `$this` so it's `$this->bdd`